# bind model to user (OneToOneField)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-users

So, I have that task,
I create driver model (int contains date of birth, last_drug_test, active_status and so on, expanded version of profile tbh).

and when I create that driver model, I use django social allauth,
if user sign in first time in app, if email is from driver's model email field
(users email == driver model email field)
then I want to make Foreignkey relationship between that user and driver model object,

my question is that if that's possible?

my solution was to create driver user profile with Driver model manually, but then user have to login with email/password and bind social login from profile settings

something like this:

```
instance = add_custom_user.save(commit=False)
instance.is_driver = True 
instance.set_password("password1234") 
instance.save()
```

but what will be better way of this